# How to assign value to the DropBox text propery?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm writing a program where user has 3 drop boxes to input date, month and a year. after user selects the values I concatenate them and check for valid  By default when a page loads I need to assign a current day, month and year to each drop box accordingly. Then I check validity of the date and pass value to the database.

My problem is that when I assign the values to the text of DropBoxes upon the loading of the page they are becoming permanent. even if the index is changed the values which are passed to the database are the ones which assigned to them when the page is loaded.

I can't actually understand what am I doing wrong:

these are the code samples which I've used:

1. I populate them with a current date values using folowing code(on the page Load event):

   ```
        Dim CurYear As Integer = DatePart("yyyy", Now)
        Dim CurDate As Integer = DatePart("d", Now)
        Dim CurMonth As String = Format(Today.Date, "MMMM")
        Dim CurDate2 As Integer = DatePart("d", Now)
        Dim CurMonth2 As String = Format(Now, "MM") 

        Dates.Text = CurDate
        Monthe.Text = CurMonth
        years.Text = CurYear
        Month2.Text = CurMonth2
        Dates2.Text = CurDate2
   ```

Than I had to synchronize the selected index of 2 the dropboxes which contain numerical value of the month and 2 digit format of the day, to to form the proper string for checking of the date

```
Protected Sub Months_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Months.SelectedIndexChanged
  Month2.SelectedIndex = Months.SelectedIndex
  TextBox3.Text = years.Text & "-" & Monthes.Text & "-" & Dates.Text
 End Sub

Protected Sub Dates_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Dates.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dates2.SelectedIndex = Dates.SelectedIndex
    TextBox3.Text = years.Text & "-" & Monthes.Text & "-" & Dates.Text
End Sub
```

And this is front end ASP code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Dates" runat="server" autopostback="true">
                      <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                      ...
                      <asp:ListItem>26</asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem>27</asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem>28</asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem>29</asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem>31</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>

                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Months" runat="server" autopostback="true" >
                      <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem>January</asp:ListItem>
                      ...
                      <asp:ListItem>November</asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem>December</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>


                    <asp:DropDownList ID="years" runat="server" autopostback="true" >
                      <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>


                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Dates2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                      <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem>01</asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem>02</asp:ListItem>
                      ....
                      <asp:ListItem>29</asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem>31</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>

                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Month2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                      <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem>01</asp:ListItem>
                      ....
                      <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Again, if I don't assign the default values to the boxes upon loading of the page it works perfectly. if i do, those values are fixed no mater what you choose

The comparevalidator:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel19" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" ValidationGroup="CompareValidatorDateTest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</ContentTemplate>
       <Triggers>
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Dates" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Monthes" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="years" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
       </Triggers>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>

       <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator3" Display="dynamic" ControlToValidate="TextBox3"
        Type="Date" Operator="LessThanEqual" Text="Please enter a valid date" runat="server"
        ValidationGroup="CompareValidatorDateTest"
```

Comment: use **findstringexact** first to get the index ...

Comment: what is findstringexact? forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Isn't there that methode in your combobox ?

Comment: no just reassigning sof selectedIndexes

Comment: I've updated my post. and palces the entire code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you didnt use `IsPostBack` property while binding the dropdown with values on page load.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

      // Bind your dropdown here here

End If
```

Comment: Why would i bring them there? it won't be updated. Will it? and what exactly should I put there?

Comment: though there is one slight problem. Beside the date validation I use compare validator to check if the date is not greater than today. But the error is not being prompted. Do you think it's the ame problem?